# Query tuning issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tuning

I'm in trouble trying to tune this following query. I used to be 100% focused in the infrastructure side of the stuff, but since August this year I'm working for a processing card company that is demanding just my "dark side" - query tuning skills.

I'd appreciate if you could provide me suggestions and tips to improve the performance of query.
Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Delivery](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Address_Name] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_Street] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_Complement] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_City] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_District] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_Number] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_State] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Address_ZipCode] [varchar](120) NULL,
[OsFk] [int] NOT NULL,
[WebstoreOrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CourierType] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Delivery] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CardId] [bigint] NULL,
[WebstoreOrderId] [int] NULL,
[WebstoreEcommerceTypeId] [tinyint] NULL,
[WebstoreChannelId] [int] NULL,
[OS_Id] [int] NULL,
[Delivery_Id] [int] NULL,
[TrackingCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[WebstoreOrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
[IsBipped] [bit] NULL,
[WebstoreCategoryId] [int] NULL,
[WebstoreOrderItemId] [int] NULL,
[Product] [int] NULL,
[IsPrePrinted] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Os](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NULL,
[OSType_Id] [int] NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
[ParentOS_Id] [int] NULL,
[HasChip] [bit] NULL,
[HasProcessingError] [bit] NULL,
[Product] [int] NULL,
[IsPrePrinted] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ServiceOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OSType](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Channels] [varchar](100) NULL,
[EcommerceTypes] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TypeCode] [int] NULL,
[DeliveryIsLabelled] [bit] NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NULL,
[Modalities] [varchar](100) NULL,
[PasswordLetterType] [int] NULL,
[Categories] [varchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Channel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Delivery_X_OrderItem] FOREIGN KEY([Delivery_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Delivery] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Delivery_X_OrderItem]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Os_X_OrderItem] FOREIGN KEY([OS_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Os] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Os_X_OrderItem]
```

And this is the query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ParentOS_Id,Id) Id, 
OSTypeId TypeId, 
OSType Type, 
SUM(Status) Status, 
SerializedOrderIds, 
SUM(StripeBlankStatus) StripeBlankStatus, 
SUM(ChipBlankStatus) ChipBlankStatus, 
SUM(StripePrePrintedStatus) StripePrePrintedStatus, 
SUM(ChipPrePrintedStatus) ChipPrePrintedStatus, 
SUM(StripeBlankId) StripeBlankId, 
SUM(ChipBlankId) ChipBlankId, 
SUM(StripePrePrintedId) StripePrePrintedId, 
SUM(ChipPrePrintedId) ChipPrePrintedId, 
CreatedAt Date, 
HasProcessingError HasProcessingError, 
SUM(BippedCardCount) BippedCardCount, 
SUM(DeliveryCount) DeliveryCount, 
SUM(StripeBlankCardCount) StripeBlankCardCount, 
SUM(ChipBlankCardCount) ChipBlankCardCount, 
SUM(StripePrePrintedCardCount) StripePrePrintedCardCount, 
SUM(ChipPrePrintedCardCount) ChipPrePrintedCardCount, 
SUM(CardCount) CardCount 
FROM ( 
     SELECT Id, 
     ParentOS_Id, 
     OSTypeId, 
     Name OSType, 
     CreatedAt, 
     Status, 
     StripeBlankStatus, 
     ChipBlankStatus, 
     StripePrePrintedStatus, 
     ChipPrePrintedStatus, 
     StripeBlankId, 
     ChipBlankId, 
     StripePrePrintedId, 
     ChipPrePrintedId, 
     HasProcessingError, 
     BippedCardCount, 
     DeliveryCount, 
     StripeBlankCardCount, 
     StripePrePrintedCardCount, 
     ChipBlankCardCount, 
     ChipPrePrintedCardCount, 
     (StripeBlankCardCount + ChipBlankCardCount + StripePrePrintedCardCount + ChipPrePrintedCardCount) AS CardCount, 
     SerializedOrderIds FROM ( 
                         SELECT OS.Id, 
                         OSType.Id OSTypeId, 
                         OSType.Name, 
                         OS.CreatedAt, 
                         OS.ParentOS_Id, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN OS.ParentOS_Id IS NULL THEN OS.Status ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_STATUS WHERE OS_STATUS.Id = OS.ID) Status, 
                         (SELECT TOP 1 OS_ERROR.HasProcessingError FROM OS OS_ERROR WHERE OS_ERROR.Id = OS.Id OR OS_ERROR.ParentOS_Id = OS.Id 
                         ORDER BY OS_ERROR.HasProcessingError DESC) AS HasProcessingError, 
                         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem TB WHERE (OS.Id = TB.OS_Id) AND TB.IsBipped = 1) AS BippedCardCount, 

                         (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT O.Delivery_Id) FROM dbo.OrderItem O JOIN dbo.Delivery D ON O.Delivery_Id = D.ID WHERE O.OS_Id = OS.Id) AS DeliveryCount, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 0 THEN OS_STATUS.STATUS ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_STATUS WHERE OS.Id = OS_STATUS.Id ) AS StripeBlankStatus, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 1 THEN OS_STATUS.STATUS ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_STATUS WHERE OS.Id = OS_STATUS.Id ) AS ChipBlankStatus, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 2 THEN OS_STATUS.STATUS ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_STATUS WHERE OS.Id = OS_STATUS.Id ) AS StripePrePrintedStatus, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 4 THEN OS_STATUS.STATUS ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_STATUS WHERE OS.Id = OS_STATUS.Id ) AS ChipPrePrintedStatus, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 0 THEN OS_IN.Id ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_IN WHERE OS.Id = OS_IN.Id ) AS StripeBlankId, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 1 THEN OS_IN.Id ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_IN WHERE OS.Id = OS_IN.Id ) AS ChipBlankId, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 2 THEN OS_IN.Id ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_IN WHERE OS.Id = OS_IN.Id ) AS StripePrePrintedId, 
                         (SELECT CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 4 THEN OS_IN.Id ELSE NULL END FROM OS OS_IN WHERE OS.Id = OS_IN.Id ) AS ChipPrePrintedId, 
                         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 0 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS StripeBlankCardCount, 
                         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 1 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS ChipBlankCardCount, 
                         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 2 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS StripePrePrintedCardCount, 
                         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 4 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS ChipPrePrintedCardCount, 
                         (SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WebstoreOrderId) AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderItem OI WHERE ISNULL(OS.ParentOS_Id,OS.ID) = OI.OS_Id FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 100000)) SerializedOrderIds 
                          FROM dbo.Os OS 
                          JOIN dbo.OSType OSType ON OSType.Id = OS.OSType_Id 
                          ) AS QUERY 
     ) RESULT 
GROUP BY ISNULL(ParentOS_Id, Id), OSType, OSTypeId, CreatedAt, HasProcessingError, SerializedOrderIds
```

Comment: Welcome. It would help if you formatted all the code consistently in a way that avoided horizontal scrolling. Have you identified a single, precise problem you'd like responses to? Editing to focus on that would help. As it stands your question is rather broad.

Comment: Is this sqlserver ?How big is the table ? Is the query running slow ? Did you check for blocking ? Post some sample data as well.

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server. The main table in the query (OS) hasn't many rows, but one of the lookup tables used (OrderItem) has (see bellow). Unfortunately I'm unable to provide sample data. But the query runs in about 10 seconds without any blocking.

I tried lots of ways to modify the query, but I didn't have success. Just one time I could reduce the time spent to just 2 seconds, but I found diferences on the number of rows in the resultset.

name: rows      
Os: 2.106
OSType: 233
OrderItem:  309.351
Delivery: 63.361

Comment: I can send the execution plan if needed.

Comment: @MarceloMoraes why 'send' it? Just post it here or on pastebin/github/whatever

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table? Especially ones for predicates and join columns?

Comment: Without seeing your execution plan and knowing the number of records, I see issues with all the subqueries in your select statement; for every record returned by the outer query, each of those subqueries are evaluated.  Very expensive.

Comment: Do you have the option to post process the dataset before sending the data to the user?  If you do, moving the substring work out of the query and doing the totaling at an application layer may speed things up.

Comment: @TomV, I'm new here and don't know exactly how to post my execution plan here.

Comment: @MarceloMoraes post the plan at [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) or even better at [sqlsentry.com](https://answers.sqlperformance.com/) and add the link in the question.

Comment: @MarceloMoraes one slight improvement (and a best practice) - `SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WebstoreOrderId)` [dont declare data type without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 4):

I would remove all the subqueries from your inner query named "QUERY" and create temp tables or CTEs instead.

Reason, each of the subqueries in your select statement are evaluated for every record your outer query generates, dragging down the performance or your query and potentially causing performance issues for the entire environment.

Below is an example to replace your order count subqueries with a join to a CTE containing a dataset of your order counts.  If your dataset is large, you can change the CTE to a temp table, giving your the flexibility to add indexes or create your own statistics.

```
;WITH CTE_ORDER(OS_Id, OrderCnt)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        OI.OS_Id,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM OrderItem OI 
    GROUP BY OI.OS_Id
)

SELECT 
OS.Id, 
CASE WHEN OS.Product = 0 THEN ORDER.OrderCnt ELSE NULL END AS StripeBlankCardCount,
CASE WHEN OS.Product = 1 THEN ORDER.OrderCnt ELSE NULL END AS ChipBlankCardCount, 
CASE WHEN OS.Product = 2 THEN ORDER.OrderCnt ELSE NULL END AS StripePrePrintedCardCount, 
CASE WHEN OS.Product = 4 THEN ORDER.OrderCnt ELSE NULL END AS ChipPrePrintedCardCount 
--(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 0 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS StripeBlankCardCount, 
--(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 1 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS ChipBlankCardCount, 
--(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 2 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS StripePrePrintedCardCount, 
--(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM OrderItem OI WHERE OS.Product = 4 AND OS.Id = OI.OS_Id) AS ChipPrePrintedCardCount, 
FROM dbo.Os OS 
    INNER JOIN dbo.OSType OSType 
        ON OSType.Id = OS.OSType_Id 
    INNER JOIN CTE_ORDER ORDER
        ON ORDER.OS_Id = OS.Id
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Corrected the name of the CTE and column name.

Comment: It helps a lot @Mike Zalansky. Thank you! I'm gonna try to do that here!!!

Comment: Great!  Feel free to ask addition questions as you refactor the code.

Comment: @YperSillyCube, thanks for catching that.  Corrected.

Comment: Thnx. And I'm not 100% sure, but using `ORDER` as an alias is probably not allowed.

Comment: @YperSillyCube, your right, it's not; I was simply trying to provide an example.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Good suggestion overall, +1. Making one CTE (or derived table) instead of 4 correlated subqueries will probably be a (serious) improvement (and temp tables may not be needed at all). If the query can be also rewritten to avoid the `GROUP BY` (with that huge list), it would also be good.

Comment: Guys, you were absolutely GREAT!!!

Comment: I coundn't find a way to solve this piece of code.

,(SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), WebstoreOrderId) AS [text()] FROM dbo.OrderItem OI WHERE ISNULL(OS.ParentOS_Id,OS.ID) = OI.OS_Id FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 100000)) SerializedOrderIds

Comment: @MarceloMoraes, is a SELECT DISTINCT required?

Comment: Commenting out or leaving out the code that creates the XML, have your changes improved the performance of your script and generating a better actual execution plan?

Comment: Yep @MikeZalansky. I cannot say that the code is elegante the way I wrote, but is faster than the original. I'm looking at this one as an improvement version 1.0. As soon as I finish, I'll start working to make adjustments.

Comment: @MikeZalansky, to be honest I don't understand 100% the business rules related to this view. I started trying to help the developer which was complaining about the slowing execution time, looking from the technical point of view only. I'm stiil trying to understand and rewrite this piece of code.